# Connecting to MongoDB from Node.js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm having a problem figuring out how to connect to the MongoDB service from my javascript file. It's been so frustrating I've been banging my head against the wall for a week now and can't figure out a solution. Please help.

I'm running Node.js and React - and am trying to connect to MongoDB to do basic CRUD functions.

**package.json**

```
{
      "name": "myapp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "main.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
        "mongodb": "^2.2.22",
        "react": "^15.3.2",
        "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
        "webpack": "^1.13.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^0.26.1"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC"
    }
```

webpack.config.js

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TodoApp from './App.jsx';
import tryThis from './datastructure.js';
ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Ok - so my react app is rendering just fine. And I want to add something like this to connect to mongodb:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  alert("Connected successfully to server");
  db.close();
});
```

but I keep getting errors.. Actually there are 8. I've pasted in the first part. Most of them are to do with the mongodb node module..
I'm so stuck - please help :(

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "net"
    at webpackMissingModule (index.js:38559)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:38559)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:39140)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:556)
    at fn (index.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:29938)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:556)
    at fn (index.js:87)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:29868)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:556) webpackMissingModule @ index.js:38559 (anonymous) @ index.js:38559 (anonymous) @ index.js:39140
__webpack_require__ @ index.js:556 fn @ index.js:87 (anonymous) @ index.js:29938
__webpack_require__ @ index.js:556 fn @ index.js:87 (anonymous) @ index.js:29868
__webpack_require__ @ index.js:556 fn @ index.js:87 (anonymous) @ index.js:8418
__webpack_require__ @ index.js:556 fn @ index.js:87 (anonymous) @ index.js:588
__webpack_require__ @ index.js:556 (anonymous) @ index.js:579 (anonymous) @ index.js:582 index.js:631 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled. index.js:631 [WDS] Errors while compiling. index.js:669 ./~/mongodb/package.json Module parse failed: C:\myapp\node_modules\mongodb\package.json Unexpected token (2:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you're trying to connect to MongoDB from the client side; if that's the case, you should change it to connect to MongoDB from the server. What's on your `main.js` file and other files?

Answer (score 0):

I found a basic CRUD sample code using **MEAN** Stack in github. Hope it helps you.

https://github.com/prabhakarreddy1234/expo-eCode